# What is the ideal way to take backup of a configuration file using perl script, which you are going to edit

Tags: perl, configuration, backup, rollback

I am trying to create a script that manipulates a configuration file . So I need to take back up of the existing configuration file , in case there is any problem during manipulation the contents of the back up file should replace the contents of the configuration file . also when rollback is given as argument to the script the contents of the backup file should replace configuration file .

Comment: interesting..... Where is your question?

Comment: I am asking for the ideal way .. like whether just copying files are enough , or I should write the contents first to a temp file and then proceed .

Comment: there is no ideal way. You can add a timestamp aftter the file and create a new with the updated config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically I'd create a file with a name based on the original file's name:

```
my $file = 'input.txt';
my $new_file = "$file.new";
```

Start reading lines from the input file, and manipulate them as necessary before writing them to the new file.

When you reach the end-of-file of the input file, close them both. Rename the input file to `"$file.old"`, then rename the new file to the old name `$file`.

You want to keep the original file intact as long as possible so it remains available in case something fails during processing.

If you have to roll back, reverse the rename process if processing completed. If processing didn't complete just delete the new file.